# Cannot get app_data passed to my facebook tab page

Tags: php, facebook

I have tried a few solutions and I cannot seem to retrieve the "app_data" that I am passing to my facebook tab page.

UPDATE----------------
For my tabbed page I am using the following and it is not working:

```
// Connect to Facebook
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
        'appId'  => $FB_APP_ID, 
        'secret' => $FB_APP_SECRET
));
$signed_request = $facebook->getSignedRequest();
echo ($signed_request["app_data"]);//Nothing is output here!
```

Comment: Check if you are getting a `signed_request` parameter in $_REQUEST at all.

Comment: Is your page tab URL redirecting to another URL? If so, the POST with the signed_data will be lost

Answer (score 1):

`app_data` in the `signed_request` is for page tab apps,

For regular canvas apps the values should be available as just `$_REQUEST['app_data']`

Answer (score 0):

```
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId' => '$testapp_id',
    'secret' => '$testapp_skey',
    'cookie' => true
));



$signed_request = $facebook->getSignedRequest();



$page_id = $signed_request["page"]["id"];
$page_admin = $signed_request["page"]["admin"];
$like_status = $signed_request["page"]["liked"];
$country = $signed_request["user"]["country"];
$locale = $signed_request["user"]["locale"];    
$fanpagid =$page_id;    

try {
$page_info  = $facebook->api("/".$page_id."?fields=link");
}catch(Exception $o) {
}

$fanpage=$page_info["link"];
$fullpageurl=$fanpage."?sk=app_".$app_id;
```

try with this code ......